# What application turn on wifi/GPS?

Tags: wi-fi, adb, usb-debugging, logging

What application turn on wifi/GPS at specific moment (**adb logcat**  or what tools to use, what strings look for)?

What installed application able to turn on wifi/GPS? Or more generally how I can get list of all installed application permissions by **adb**, **adb shell** or another tools from Android phone/SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Any app with the permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` can trigger GPS – unless you've explicitly switched off GPS location with your device settings. To scan for possible candidates, you can use a [Permission checker](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=194). There's e.g. [Permission explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.carlocriniti.android.permission_explorer) which allows you to browse installed apps by permissions, so you can limit your watch to relevant candidates.

[image: Permission Explorer: Categories] [image: Permission Explorer: Apps by permission] [image: LBE]
<sup>*Permission Explorer:* categories, apps by permission; LBE (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

If your device is rooted, there are also other means. I'm e.g. using *LBE* to protect my privacy. Concerning location, I can restrict on a per-app base whether an app can always access it, never access it, or I want to be asked when it tries. The latter method should definitely bring up your culprit – and even in case you missed the event, there are always LBE's logs (accessible from inside the app) you can check.